# Make link white

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyph

I linked to a bootstrap stylesheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Just for the glyphicon library but now all my  links are blue. How can I overwrite the bootstrap blue link color? When I try to change the A color in my CSS it doesn't affect the bootstrap - must load after it or something.

Thank you

Comment: Either use a more specific selector, swap the stylesheets in the cascade, or ***cringe*** use `!important`. If you're not pulling from a CDN, you can always modify the bootstrap file itself.

Comment: Bootstrap has fairly shallow selectors -- if you make your anchor links - color: white; and put your CSS after you load your bootstrap. You can also download glyphicons on their own - http://glyphicons.com/

Comment: "Bootstrap has fairly shallow selectors -- if you make your anchor links - color: white; and put your CSS after you load your bootstrap. You can also download glyphicons on their own - glyphicons.com – Mathias Rechtzigel 5 mins ago"---the solution. Thank you

Comment: Sometimes it helps to go back to your fundamentals and learn how css actualy works. I know it may seem like a waste of time because you're not "getting anything done", but it will save you tons of time in the long run. Try this for starters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

Comment: do you *need* bootstrap?  FWIW: Bootstrap 4 removed the glyphicons.  They can be installed by cdn on their own

Answer (score 0):

You can just apply the color to your `a` tags like so:

```
a {
  color:white;
}
```

You could also give your `a` tag a class and target it specifically:

```
<a class="anchor" href="#">Do Things</a>

a.anchor {
  color:white
}
```

Just **make sure your style sheet is loading after the bootstrap style sheet** (put the custom stylesheet below it in the code).